# how do i get the name of a component in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just dragged a UIImageview onto a storyboard in xcode 5. I am coming from .NET where this would add an object of type UIImageView to the main form. Is this the way to think about it in IOS? Where do I click in the xcode IDE to get the name of the instance of UIImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dragged a UIImageView into a storyboard.  You need to see which view controller this UIImageView object lives in and then you can connect that UIImageView to [an IBOutlet](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ios-development/build-an-iphone-crystal-ball-app/getting-started/what-is-an-iboutlet), which is how your view controller (the implementation or code for which you're working on, which also happens to be a subclass of UIViewController) will interact with the UIImageView object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a IBOutlet in the corresponding ViewController.h file like this.

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView ;
```

Then in your ViewController.m , use @synthesize after @implementation tag.

Then go back to the Interface Builder and connect the IBOutlet myImageView to your ImageView which you have dragged there. Hope it helps.